# How to include HTML5 based games in tvOS custom apps?

Tags: html, ios, swift, tvos, tvml

We have implemented a tvOS app, its in App Store. Now we would like to introduce some HTML5 games in our app as a feature. We already have HTML5 games so we don't have to implement newly. 
So how to include these games in my app. We got to know that we can't use WebKit in tvOS.

1. Is it possible to use HTML5 based code in our tvOS apps ?
2. If not possible is there any alternative way like 3rd parties or any tools which will convert HTML5 so that we can use ?
3. Is there any better way that we can implement HTML5 kind of games ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to use html in this manner on tvOS, and there is no tool to just transfer html to swift since they are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some wrapper like Cordova  https://cordova.apache.org/ to deploy your html projects as native. It could be deployed on iOS or Android.

Comment: ok but can we use Cordova for tvOS ? I can see many ways to use HTML5 in iOS apps but not in tvOS